# Nested for iteration loops and transfer of some values logic issue

Tags: c#, object, loops, for-loop, iteration

Alright...I am here looking for some bread crumbs.

This is my code:

```
     using System;

     namespace Project4
     {
     class Program
     {
     static void Main()
     {
        int total = 1;

        Console.WriteLine("Month \tAdult \tBaby \tTotal");
        Console.WriteLine("1 \t1 \t0 \t0");

        while (total < 5)
        {
            for (int m = 1; m < 5; m++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}", m);
                for (int a = 1; a < 5; a++)
                {


                    Console.Write("\t{0}", a);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

It is very incomplete....

I basically have iteration logic dumb moment. You have Month, Adult Bear, Baby Bear, and Total Bears

Month  Adult  Baby  Total

1     1         0        1

2     1         1        2

3     2         1        3

4     3         2        5

5     5         3        8

ect

Every month the adult has a baby. The next month that baby becomes a adult. But also the current adults have 1 baby each.....if you noticed by the matrix.

So I am trying to iterate the births of bears and also the transfer of babies to adults month after month.

I get caught up on the transfer part of the iteration....I have been thinking about using objects but again....not sure how to transfer.

Any hints or direction be great =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the adults and babies separately.

```
int nBabies = 0; //start with no babies and 1 adult.
int nAdults = 1;

Console.WriteLine("Month\tAdults\tBabies\tTotal\n");
//loop through 12 month period.
for(int m = 0; m < 12; m++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", m + 1, nAdults, nBabies, nAdults + nBabies));
    nAdults += nBabies; //each baby from the last iteration becomes an adult.
    nBabies = (nAdults - nBabies); //each adult from last month has a baby.
}
```

Comment: Hey great! Thanks for the breakthrough I was able to pick it apart and rewrote it so I understood. Great Help. I was def over thinking how many for statements I needed.